# Excel vlookup on two dimensions AND multiple column criteria

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am looking for a formula to reference a value from a table based on **two column values and one row value**. I tried for hours with different sumifs, match, etc. formulas but nothing worked. An example would look as follows:

```
Manager  Marketplace  Jan  Feb  Mar
mgr1     US           312  546  987
mgr1     DE           546  329  715
mgr2     FR           267  195  546
```

The formula should find the correct value if given for example mgr1, US and Feb.

Any Ideas?
Best,
Moritz

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
=INDEX(C2:E4,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A4="mgr1")*(B2:B4="US"),0,1),0),MATCH("Feb",C1:E1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX(A:E,MATCH("mgr1"&"US",A:A&B:B,0),MATCH("Feb",1:1,0))`

This is an example of a two way lookup, concatenating the vertical lookup section of the index formula.

Comment: Does that require CSE to be effective?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=INDEX(C:E, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($2:$9)/((A$2:A$9=H2)*(B$2:B$9=I2)), 1), MATCH(J2, C$1:E$1, 0))
```

[image]